# printing groups in 4 column report in crystal 2008

Tags: crystal-reports, oracle11g, report

I want to print a report in crystal 2008. This is 4 column report. My source query is in oracle 11g.

layout of report is something like that:
List of consumers feeder wise/tariff wise

```
> Feeder/Tariff        10002           10003         10004         10005
> a-1                    216             300           230            14
> b-1                     23               3            17            19
> c-1                     26               4            19            25
```

Comment: what is your requirement?

Comment: On which field do you want to group the records?